# java.lang.NullPointerException in my AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am getting an NPE in this code, I need a fix very quickly, can someone give me a hand?

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class GetXML extends AsyncTask<String, String, BirdData> {

public GetXML(){

}

/**
 * background
 */
@Override
protected BirdData doInBackground(String... params) {
    String GetWikiID = params[0];
 // All static variables
    String URL = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/life/"+GetWikiID+".rdf";
    // XML node keys

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
    System.out.println("test3");
    System.out.println(doc.getElementById("dc:description").getTextContent());
    return null;
}

/**
 * on getting result
 */
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(BirdData result) {

}
}
```

I am using this code to call it:

```
System.out.println(WikiID);
new GetXML().execute(WikiID);
```

and the error is this:

```
    08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 45: http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/tools/search/Type text here...
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost.<init>(HttpPost.java:79)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at com.swift.birdspot.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:36)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at com.swift.birdspot.GetWikiID.doInBackground(GetWikiID.java:31)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at com.swift.birdspot.GetWikiID.doInBackground(GetWikiID.java:1)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-08 16:04:17.284: E/AndroidRuntime(17971):    ... 5 more
```

Comment: If you're in a hurry then it would speed things along if you posted the logcat

Comment: Do you have the permissions to use `INTERNET` in the `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: If you are doing anything in `onPostExecute()` then you may get `NPE` since you are returning `null` in `doInBackground()`

Comment: Based on your edit: `IllegalArgumentException != NullPointerException`. You use an invalid URL character in `WikiID`.

Comment: Its not `NPE` its `IllegalArgumentException` check your `URL`

Comment: `http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/tools/search/Type text here...` is not a valid URL. Have you tried url-encoding first?

Comment: What is WikiID's value?

Comment: Yes, and that part does not return errors, its the code I posted

Comment: be something like "Common_Kingfisher"

Comment: @SwiftAppDesign well, no, its value is `Type text here...`, of which the first space gives the exception.

Comment: Nope, cus you edit that and then send it

Comment: @SwiftAppDesign check the log: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 45: http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/tools/search/Type text here...`

Comment: hmm, then why is it not pulling my edited text?

Comment: dRuntime(17971): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 45: http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/tools/search/Type text here...

Comment: Wait, nope, its returning the right wikid value.

Comment: your exception is absolutely not in the code you posted. (extra tip : it's in `com.swift.birdspot.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:36)`)

Comment: To be sure you can use `java.net.URLEncoder.encode(GetWikiID, "utf-8");` to make sure its URL friendly

Comment: Ah, that was it, adding url encoding to my json parser fixed it, thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that there are invalid characters (space characters) on the following URL:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/nature/tools/search/Type text here...
```

You should fix this URL and your problem will be solved!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I needed to do was url encode inside my jsonparser class.